# How to add class to anchor using wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, links, post-class

Sorry if my post duplicate but i can't find best solution for my problem. I'm newbie on develop WP theme. Now i'd like to add class to current li and last li, but i don't know how to do? Hope someone help.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="selected">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="last">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress does in fact add a current class by default:

check where it says:

```
<li id="menu-item-1688" class="current-menu-item">
```

Within your source code.

Now as for the other item, this is a bit tricky.

There is two ways to do it assuming that you need the last item for styling.

**Option #1** is with pure CSS using the [last-of-type selector.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/last-of-type/)

**Option #2**, is using the [get_wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) as opposed to `wp_nav_menu` and once you are inside the `foreach`, you compare it using [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) and the current index of said `foreach` to add the css class dinamically.

**Edit:** If you are a bit new to Wordpress theming, I would definitely go with option number 1 despite not having full browser coverage.